# Scraping: unable to get JSON using Twitter API

Tags: r, twitter, pagination, web-scraping

My objective is to use the Twitter API in order to retrieve all tweets from  posted between January 1st, 2016 and the present

First I tried the the `searchTwitter()` method from the `twitteR` package but found that there is a rate limit, so, for example, when I input:

```
> tweets <- searchTwitter("from:@BernieSanders", n=1000, lang="en", since="2016-01-01")
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  1000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 75
```

The API restricts to the amount of tweets that can be retrieved to 75.

One of the workarounds seems to be using twitter's REST API, but I am getting an error when I follow the steps on the Twitter developer's page

```
url <- 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40BernieSanders'
page <- GET(url)
print(http_status(page))


library(ROAuth)
library(httr)
library(twitteR)


# Set API Keys
api_key <- "####"
api_secret <- "####"
access_token <- "####"
access_token_secret <- "###"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)


    url <- 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40BernieSanders'
    page <- GET(url)
> print(http_status(page))
$category
[1] "Client error"

$reason
[1] "Bad Request"

$message
[1] "Client error: (400) Bad Request"
```

I have also tried using `RSelenium` and `Phantomjs` to start browser and automate the scrolling down a page, but I am new to scraping and have been unable to overcome the issue of Twitter's [special pagination technique](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines) that uses maxID and sinceID. I am not sure, for example, which sinceID would be associated with the date January 1, 2016, or what that maxID would be.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!